# Find first open tag using regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I tried to find the first open tag using regex, but for some reason, it finds the last one.

Example: http://regex101.com/r/pY4bI0

The green part should end at the second line. What do I wrong? How should I fix it?

Comment: `/<\w[^>]*>/` should do the trick.

Comment: @IterAtor What does "doesn't work" mean? "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem. What happened when you tried it? Did you get an error message? Did you get incorrect results? Did you get *no results*? If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect? What were you expecting instead? Did you get *any* correct results? If so, what were they? Don't make us guess.

Comment: Please only use external links as an illustration and put the relevant code in your post here: questions on StackOverflow should be stand alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about just this?

```
(\<\w.*?\>)
```

http://regex101.com/r/eM4fK3